# Index of intersection of finite index subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to understand this proof https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128549/205193 which does not seem complicated but I don't understand why :

**why $p(x)=p(y)$, implies that $x$ and $y$ are in the same left coset of $H$ and the same left coset of $K$.**

for exemple, if $h(x)=2$, $k(x)=3$ and $h(y)=3, k(y)=2$ dont we have $p(x)=p(y)$ even if they arent in the same cosets?

and why do we have that:

**If $x$ and $y$ are in different left cosets of $H∩K$, then $p(x)≠p(y)$**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\langle h(x),k(x)\rangle$ in that answer denotes an *ordered* pair (more often written $(h(x),k(x))$), so $\langle h(x),k(x)\rangle=\langle h(y),k(y)\rangle$ iff $h(x)=h(y)$ and $k(x)=k(y)$.

If $p(x)=p(y)$, then $h(x)=h(y)$, so $x^{-1}y\in H$.  Similarly, $k(x)=k(y)$, so $x^{-1}y\in K$.  Thus $x^{-1}y\in H\cap K$, so they are in the same left coset of $H\cap K$.  This is the contrapositive of your second question.

Comment: Thanks I thought the notation was scalar product..

Comment: Ah, I see (from your example I thought you thought it was an unordered pair).  Angle brackets do often mean scalar product, but they are also sometimes used for ordered pairs (or ordered $n$-tuples), and in this context the latter makes a lot more sense!