# prove that $H\cap K$ have finite index in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a group and $H,K$ are two subgroups of finite index in $G$, prove that $H\cap K$ is of finite index in $G$. Can you find upper bound for index of $H\cap K$  in $G$?

Since $a(H\cap K$) $\subseteq aH\cap aK$, and since there are only a finite many choices for $aH$ and $aK$, there are only finite many choices for $a(H\cap K$)

Is it correct ?

What about upper bound of index of $H\cap K$?

Comment: This will work. In fact $a(H \cap K) = aH \cap aK.$

Comment: @PhilipHoskins how to prove reverse inclusion ?

Comment: I just posted a hint @Eklavya

Comment: It is essentially just reversing the steps in the proof that $a(H \cap K) \subseteq aH \cap aK$

Comment: @PhilipHoskins Please check: We can actually prove this with only $\subseteq$ and not $=$? If that's right, Eklavya is brilliant!

Comment: @JackBauer Are you asking if there is a proof that doesn't invoke equality or are you asking to verify that $a(H \cap K) = aH \cap aK$? The latter is certainly true. In general, $aH \cap bK$ will be either a left coset of $H \cap K$ or empty. When $a = b$, the intersection contains $a$ in particular, so it cannot be empty. 

If Eklavya is still around these days, they should write up and accept their own answer. None of the other answers posted actually addressed their (correct) attempt at a proof.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins Proof that doesn't invoke equality but invokes $\subseteq$. Can it be done? Thank you!

Comment: @JackBauer Sure. I can't think of an easier argument than proving the equality.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins Double check please: You said "This will work." Is "this" with only $\subseteq$, or referring to "$=$" ? I was confusing both of us :)

Comment: @JackBauer I think the point I was trying to make was that Eklavya's approach to the proof would work, not that it was correct as written. The gap in their argument with $\subseteq$ is that even though each coset of $H \cap K$ is contained in an intersection of cosets of $H$ and $K$, there's no apparent reason that one of the intersections can't contain an infinite number of cosets. Equality fixes that. Every coset is obtained by intersection. So if you consider the $[G:H] \cdot [G:K]$ possible intersections, you have listed all cosets of $H \cap K$ with some possible multiplicty.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you are comfortable with group actions: Let G act on the set $S=G/H \times G/K$ (as coset spaces) by the law $g \star (aH,bK)=(gaH,gbK)$.Consider the element $(H,K)$ of $S$. Stab($(H,K)=H \cap K)$. Now we know that $[G: Stab((H,K)]=|Orb((H,K))| \leq |S|=[G:H][G:K]$. This upper bound is achievable (not too hard to find an example).

Comment: $H, K$ may not be normal subgroups of $G$. So You can not take quotient .

Answer (score 4):

By [multiplicativity of the subgroup index](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Index_is_multiplicative), we have
$$
[G: H \cap K] = [G : K] [K : H \cap K] \, .
$$
We claim that $[K : H \cap K] \leq [G : H]$.  Define a map
\begin{align*}
f: \frac{K}{H \cap K} &\to \frac{G}{H}\\
k (H \cap K) &\mapsto kH \, .
\end{align*}
It is straightforward to show that $f$ is well-defined.  We now show $f$ is injective.  Suppose $k_1 H = f(k_1(H \cap K)) = f(k_2(H \cap K)) = k_2 H$. Then $k_2^{-1} k_1 \in H$, so $k_2^{-1} k_1 \in H \cap K$, hence $k_1(H \cap K) = k_2(H \cap K)$ as desired.  Thus $f$ is injective, so $[K : H \cap K] \leq [G : H]$.  Therefore
$$
[G: H \cap K] = [G : K] [K : H \cap K] \leq [G : K] [G : H] \, .
$$
Since the indices on the righthand side are finite by assumption, this shows that the index of $H \cap K$ is also finite.

Comment: @45465 It's just the set of left cosets of $H \cap K$ in $K$, so sets of the form $k(H \cap K)$. In the same way that $G/H$ is the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: @45465 $k_1 H = k_2 H$ means by definition that $k_2^{-1} k_1 \in H$. And $k_1, k_2 \in K$ by assumption since they are representatives of cosets in $K/(H \cap K)$.

Comment: @45465 Ah sorry, I didn't notice the typo. Thanks. Well-defined just means that if I choose 2 different representatives for the coset, $k_1, k_2 \in K$ with $k_1(H \cap K) = k_2(H \cap K)$, then $f$ gives the same output for both of them. So I think yes: it's just showing that $f$ is actually a function on $K/(H \cap K)$.

Comment: $H, K$ may not be normal subgroups of $G$. So You can not take quotient .'

Comment: @jaysrikrishna The quotient isn't a group if the subgroup is not normal, but one can always consider the set of left cosets. That's what I mean by $G/H$ and $G/(H \cap K)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x \in aH \cap aK$, then $xa^{-1} \in H$ and $xa^{-1} \in K$. So what can you say about $x$ and $a$ modulo $H \cap K?$

Comment: $x\in  aH\cap aK $ then $x=ah,x=ak$ for some $h,k$.it gives me $h=k$.hence $h\in H\cap K$ hence $x\in a(H\cap  K)$. is it wright ??

Comment: now is it correct?

Comment: because for $aH,aK$ we have finite number of choices .hence only finite choice for $a(H\cap K)$

Comment: what about upper bound for $a(H\cap K)$? i think i would be mn. where m and n are index of $H,K$ .is it right

Comment: Would the down-voter be so kind as to given an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is the same problem as Problem 12 on p.47 in Herstein's book.

Since I could not solve this problem, I referred to "An Introduction to Algebraic Systems" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.
The following 3 problems are in this Matsuzaka's book:

> Problem 2 (on p.60)
> When $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, we denote the index of $H$ in $G$ by $i_G(H)$.
> Suppose $H,K$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H\supset K$.
> Suppose $i_G(H)<+\infty$ and $i_H(K)<+\infty$.
> Then, $i_G(K)<+\infty$ and $$i_G(K)=i_G(H)i_H(K)$$ holds.
>
> My solution:
> Let $i_G(H)=m$ and $i_H(K)=n$.
> Then, we can write $G/H=\{g_1H,\dots,g_mH\}$ for some $g_1,\dots,g_m\in G$.
> Then, we can write $H/K=\{h_1K,\dots,h_nK\}$ for some $h_1,\dots,h_n\in H$.
> Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $G$.
> Then, $x\in g_iH$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.
> So, $x=g_ih$ for some $h\in H$.
> $h\in h_jK$ for some $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.
> So, $h=h_jk$ for some $k\in K$.
> Therefore, $x=g_ih_jk\in g_ih_jK$.
> So, $i_G(K)\leq m\cdot n$.
> Next we prove that $\#\{g_ih_jK\mid i\in\{1,\dots,m\}\text{ and }j\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}=m\cdot n$.
> Let $(i,j)\neq (k,l)$, where $i,k\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $j,l\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.
> We prove that $g_ih_jK\neq g_kh_lK$.
> Assume that $g_ih_jK\neq g_kh_lK$ doesn't hold.
> Then, $g_ih_jK=g_kh_lK$ must hold.
> So, $g_ih_j=g_kh_lk$ for some $k\in K$.
> $g_i=g_kh_lkh_{j}^{-1}\in g_kH$.
> So, $g_iH=g_kH$.
> So, $i=k$.
> Since $g_ih_jK=g_ih_lK$, $h_jK=h_lK$.
> So, $j=l$.
> So, $(i,j)=(k,l)$.
> This is a contradiction.
> So, $g_ih_jK\neq g_kh_lK$ holds.
> So, $\#\{g_ih_jK\mid i\in\{1,\dots,m\}\text{ and }j\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}=m\cdot n$ holds.
> Therefore, $i_G(K)=i_G(H)i_H(K)$.

> Problem 3 (on p.60)
> Suppose $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$ and $i_G(K)<+\infty$.
> Then, $i_H(H\cap K)<+\infty$ and $i_H(H\cap K)\leq i_G(K)$ holds.
>
> My solution:
> $H/H\cap K\ni h(H\cap K)\mapsto hK\in G/K$ is well-defined since $h^{-1}h^{'}\in H\cap K$ implies $h^{-1}h^{'}\in K$.
> Suppose that $hK=h^{'}K$.
> Then $h^{-1}h^{'}\in K$.
> Since $h,h^{'}\in H$, $h^{-1}h^{'}\in H\cap K$.
> So, $h(H\cap K)=h^{'}(H\cap K)$.
> So, this well-defined mapping is injective.
> So, $i_H(H\cap K)<+\infty$ and $i_H(H\cap K)\leq i_G(K)$ must hold.

> Problem 4 (Poincare) (on p.60)
> Suppose that $H_1,\dots,H_n$ be subgroups of $G$ and $i_G(H_i)<+\infty$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.
> Then, $i_G(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_n)<+\infty$ and $$i_G(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_n)\leq i_G(H_1)\cdots i_G(H_n)$$ hold.
>
> My solution:
> Obviously, $i_G(H_1)<+\infty$ and $i_G(H_1)\leq i_G(H_1)$ hold.
> Assume that $i_G(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k)<+\infty$ and $i_G(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k)\leq i_G(H_1)\cdots i_G(H_k)$ hold.
> By Problem 3, $$i_{H_{k+1}}(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k\cap H_{k+1})<+\infty$$ and $$i_{H_{k+1}}(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k\cap H_{k+1})\leq i_G(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k)$$ hold.
> By Problem 2, $$i_{G}(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k\cap H_{k+1})=i_G(H_{k+1})i_{H_{k+1}}(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k\cap H_{k+1})<+\infty$$ holds.
> So, $$i_{G}(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k\cap H_{k+1})\leq i_G(H_{k+1})i_G(H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k)\leq\\ i_G(H_1)\cdots i_G(H_k)i_G(H_{k+1})$$ holds.