# Indexes of Intersection is less than Index of Original?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was looking at the Rutgers 1993 Sample Qual, Page 2 Question 3

http://www.math.rutgers.edu/docman-lister/math-main/academics/graduate/qualifying-exam/1460-sample/file

Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ subgroups where $H$ has finite index in $G$. Prove that $H \cap K$ has finite index in $K$.

Now as I was playing around with this I read the wikipedia article and came across property 3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup#Properties

$$ |H : H \cap K| \le |G: K| $$

Which makes this proof... (dare I say it?) trivial (simply swap the K and H and we know that finite things are less than finite things.

But now I'm wondering how do I prove this powerful property in the first place? as Wiki doesn't give a citation.

I did some digging on math.se and this question:

[prove that $H\cap K$ have finite index in G](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605121/prove-that-h-cap-k-have-finite-index-in-g)

Is very relevant. But in the first answer they merely state its easy to show that the map they have given is well defined. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to show that.

Comment: It follows the same steps as the steps to show that it is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : H/(H \cap K) \to G/K$, where $/$ denotes the set of left cosets (not quotient), be constructed with $h(H \cap K) \mapsto hK$.

To prove that $f$ is well-defined: suppose $h(H \cap K) = h'(H \cap K)$. Then, $h'^{-1}h(H \cap K) = H \cap K$, so $h'^{-1}h \in H \cap K$, and in particular $h'^{-1}h \in K$, so $h'^{-1}hK = K$, so $hK = h'K$.

To prove that $f$ is injective: suppose $hK = h'K$ for some $h,h' \in H$. Then, $h'^{-1}hK = K$, so $h'^{-1}h \in K$. Since $h,h' \in H$, we also have $h'^{-1}h \in H$. Therefore, $h'^{-1}h \in H \cap K$. Therefore, $h'^{-1}h (H \cap K) = H \cap K$, which allows us to conclude that $h(H \cap K) = h'(H \cap K)$. Therefore, $f$ is an injection.

Therefore, $|H:H \cap K| \le |G:K|$.

Comment: What does the notation $h(H \cap K) \rightarrow hK$ mean?

Comment: $\mapsto$ `\mapsto` means that the particular element on the left-hand side is sent to that element on the right-hand side. For example, the square function sends $x$ to $x^2$, so it is denoted by $x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: Okay so we are saying consider the coset containing an element $y$ in $H / (H \cap K)$  and map that coset to the coset containing $y$ in $G/K$?

Comment: That is correct.