# Upper bound for index $|G:H\cap K|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question is already answered here [prove that $H\cap K$ have finite index in G](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605121/prove-that-h-cap-k-have-finite-index-in-g) 
But I had written solution in another way.

Let $G$ be group and $H$ and $K$ be its subgroup with finite index then we have to show bounds for index of $H \cap K$ as $[a,b]\leq |G:H\cap K|\leq ab$ where $a=|G:H|$ and $b=|G:K|$
 $|G:H\cap K|=|G:H||H:H\cap K|=|G:K||K:H\cap K|$
As $a$ and $b$ both divide $|G:H\cap K|$, we have $[a,b]$ divide $|G:H\cap K|$ that is $[a,b]\leq |G:H\cap K|$
Now the only thing that remains is to show that $|G:H\cap K|\leq ab$

This can be simplied to show by $|G:H\cap K|=|G:H||H:H\cap K|\leq |G:H||G:K|$
That is $|H:H\cap K|\leq |G:K|$
That is coset of K in G are more than Coset of $H \cap K$ in H .But How to Prove that?
How to proceed further? 
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: You seem to have proved it. What is your question?

Comment: I am not able to write answer of last claim second last line

Comment: @DerekHolt . coset of K in G are more than Coset of $H \cap K in H .But How to Prove that?Sir Please Help me I am still Stuck

Comment: If $h_1,h_2 \in H$ with $(H \cap K)h_1 \ne (H \cap K)h_2$, then $Kh_1 \ne Kh_2$, so $|H:H \cap K| \le |G:K|$.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Sir Now I understand

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

Let $x_1H, \ldots, x_aH$ be all the distinct left cosets of $H$ in $G$, and $y_1K, \ldots, y_bK$ be all the distinct left cosets of $K$ in $G$.

To show that $|G: H\cap K|\leq ab$, it suffices to show that whenever we have $z_1, \ldots, z_{ab+1}\in G$, then $z_iH\cap K=z_jH\cap K$ for some $i\neq j$.

To see this, we have by the pigeonhole principle that some $z_{i_1}, \ldots, z_{i_{b+1}}$ are in the same left coset of $H$.

Renumbering these for convenience, we may say that $z_1, \ldots, z_{b+1}$ are in the same left coset of $H$.

Again, by the pigeonhole principle, some two of $z_1, \ldots, z_{b+1}$, say $z_i$ and $z_j$ with $i\neq j$, are in the same left coset of $K$.

So we have $z_i$ and $z_j$ are in the same left coset of $H$ and the same left coset of $K$.

Thus $z_j^{-1}z_i\in H\cap K$, and consequently we have $z_iH\cap K=z_j H\cap K$.

This finishes the proof.