# Prove $[G:H]=[G':H']$ where $H$ and $H'$ are corresponding subgroups preferably without product or quotient groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

For a surjective homomorphism $\varphi: G \to G'$ where $\ker \varphi \subseteq H$, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ that corresponds to $H'$, a subgroup of $G'$, the correspondence theorem implies $$\varphi(H)=H',$$ $$\varphi^{-1}(H')=H,$$ $$|H|=|H'| |\ker(\varphi)|,$$ $$\varphi(G)=G'$$ From counting formula, $$|H|=[H: \ker \varphi]|\ker \varphi|,$$ $$|G|=[G: \ker \varphi]|\ker \varphi|,$$ $$|G|=[G: H]|H|,$$ $$|G'|=[G': H]|H'|$$

Additionally, from $\varphi: G \to G'$ and from $\varphi|_H : H \to H'$,  $$[G:\ker \varphi] = |\varphi(G)|=|G'|,$$ $$[H:\ker (\varphi|_H)] = [H:\ker \varphi \cap H]$$$$ = [H:\ker \varphi] = |\varphi|_H(H)|=|\varphi(H)|=|H'|$$

Proving $[G:H]=[G':H']$ is easy if I can divide ([Blake Griffith of Github proves like this](https://github.com/cowlicks/algebraic-structures-373k/tree/master/homework/h3)):

$$[G:H]=\frac{|G|}{|H|}=\frac{|G|}{|H'||\ker \varphi|}$$$$=\frac{[G:\ker \varphi]|\ker \varphi|}{|H'||\ker \varphi|}$$$$=\frac{[G:\ker \varphi]}{|H'|}=\frac{|G'|}{|H'|}=[G':H']$$

**But if I can't, what can I do?** From

$$|G'| = [G':H']|H'| = [G:H]|H'|$$

- If $|G'| < \infty$, then $|H'| < \infty$ and then there is no problem.
- If both $[G:H] = [G':H'] = \infty$ then there is no problem.
- If $|G'| = \infty$, then ($[G':H'] = \infty$ or $|H'| = \infty$) and ($[G:H] = \infty$ or $|H'| = \infty$).
- If $|G'| = \infty$ and we don't have that both $[G:H] = [G':H'] = \infty$, then we are left with 5 cases, and each case assumes $|H'| = \infty$.

Let $b':=[G':H'],b:=[G:H]$.

1. $b < b' < \infty$
2. $b' < b < \infty$
3. $b<\infty=b'$
4. $b'<\infty=b$
5. $b = b' < \infty$

For 1 and 3, I can derive a contradiction: Let $G$ be partitioned $$G=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}z_iH \implies G' = \varphi(G) = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\varphi(z_iH) = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\varphi(z_i)H' \implies b'=b<\infty$$

For 2 and 4, I am stuck: Let $G'$ be partitioned $$G'=\bigcup_{j=1}^{m}w_jH' \implies G = \varphi^{-1}(G') = \bigcup_{j=1}^{m}\varphi^{-1}(w_jH') = \bigcup_{j=1}^{m}\varphi^{-1}(w_j)H$$

where

$$\varphi^{-1}(w_j)H := \{u_jh \mid \varphi(u_j)=w_j, h \in H\}$$

I don't know how to derive cosets from this since $\varphi$ is not assumed to be injective, a $\varphi^{-1}(w_j)$ might be infinite, and I don't even know if $$\bigcup_{j=1}^{m}\varphi^{-1}(w_jH') = \bigcup_{j=1}^{m}\varphi^{-1}(w_j)H$$ I proved $\supseteq$, but I think $\subseteq$ is not true if not injective.

Finally, I did not use disjointedness in the partitioning. That could be helpful.

Comment: I don't have the time to fully understand your work, but I have one remark.  Your work seems to require that $G$ be finite.  However, the result is true even if $G$ is not finite.  Let $K$ be the kernel $\ker(\varphi)$.  Then, we have the following isomorphisms of left $G$-sets: $$G/H\cong {(G/K)}\big/{(H/K)}\cong G'/H'\,.$$  Thus, $[G:H]=\big[(G/K):(H/K)\big]=[G':H']$ whether or not $G$ is finite, or $[G:H]$ is finite.

Comment: @Batominovski How do you do this without quotient groups? This is an exercise from Artin's Algebra Ch. 2.10. Quotient groups is still in Ch 2.12. (Of course I cheated when by using product sets when product sets are not introduced until Ch 2.12). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ that contains $K:=\ker(\varphi)$.  Therefore, $H/K$ is a subgroup of the factor group $G/K$.  Define
$$f:(G/H)\to \big((G/K)\big/(H/K)\big)\text{ by setting }f(gH):=g(H/K)\text{ for every }g\in G\,.$$
Show that this is a well defined function (and in fact, it is a homomorphism of [left $G$-sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action)).  Furthermore, verify that $f$ is bijective.

Now, the surjective map $\varphi:G\to G'$ induces a function $\Phi:\big((G/K)\big/(H/K)\big)\to (G'/H')$ via
$$\Phi\big(g(H/K)\big):=\varphi(g)\,H'\text{ for each }g\in G\,.$$
(This is again an isomorphism of left $G$-sets, if we equip $G'$ with the left $G$-action from $\varphi$, namely, $g\cdot g':=\varphi(g)\,g'$ for every $g\in G$ and $g'\in G'$.)  The definition of $\Phi$ is inspired the group isomorphism $\phi:(G/K)\to G'$ induced by $\varphi$, which is given by $\phi(gK):=\varphi(g)$ for every $g\in G$.

Consequently, $\psi:=\Phi\circ f:(G/H)\to (G'/H')$ is simply the bijective function
$$\psi(gH)=\varphi(g)\,H'\text{ for all }g\in G\,,\tag{*}$$
which is also an isomorphism of left $G$-sets.  This shows that
$$[G:H]=|G/H|=|G'/H'|=[G':H']\,,$$
which is also equal to $\big[(G/K):(H/K)\big]=\big|(G/K)\big/(H/K)\big|$.

**P.S.:** You can directly define $\psi$ using (*) and show that it is a bijective function, without defining $f$ and $\Phi$.  In this way, you don't need to deal with factor groups $G/K$ and $H/K$.  However, I think that understanding the correspondence of $G/H$ or $G'/H'$ with $(G/K)\big/(H/K)$ gives you a new perspective.

Comment: Please tell me how to show $\psi(g)=\varphi(g)H', \psi G \to \{\text{cosets of $H'$}\}$ is bijective. I think $\psi$ is surjective because $\varphi$ is surjective. As for showing $\psi$ is injective, is it like the answer of Quasicoherent in this question [prove that H∩K have finite index in G](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605121/prove-that-h-cap-k-have-finite-index-in-g) ?

Comment: There are three steps you need to check.  First, prove that $\psi$ as given by (*) is well defined.  Second, show that $\psi$ is surjective, as you have given an argument.  Third, check that $\psi$ is injective.

Comment: For the first part, suppose that $g_1H=g_2H$ with $g_1,g_2\in G$.  We need to verify that $$\varphi(g_1)H'=\psi(g_1H)=\psi(g_2H)=\varphi(g_2)H'\,.$$ This amounts to showing that $$\varphi\left(g_1^{-1}g_2\right)=\big(\varphi(g_1)\big)^{-1}\,\varphi(g_2)\in H'\,.$$  However, the above equality is true iff $g_1^{-1}g_2\in \varphi^{-1}(H')=H$.  (Since $g_1H=g_2H$, $g_1^{-1}g_2\in H$ does hold.)

Comment: For the third part about injectivity, you just twist the proof of the first part a little.  Suppose that $\psi(g_1H)=\psi(g_2H)$ for some $g_1,g_2\in G$.  You need to justify that $g_1H=g_2H$.   Since $$\varphi(g_1)H'=\psi(g_1H)=\psi(g_2H)=\varphi(g_2)H'\,.$$ This  means $$\varphi\left(g_1^{-1}g_2\right)=\big(\varphi(g_1)\big)^{-1}\,\varphi(g_2)\in H'\,.$$  However, thus $g_1^{-1}g_2\in \varphi^{-1}(H')=H$.   This gives $g_1H=g_2H$, as desired.

Comment: And be careful.  The domain of $\psi$ is the left $H$-coset space $G/H$, not $G$.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up comments! But why not $G$? $\psi$ looks to be capable of handling $g$ as input.

Comment: Yes, but you want a bijection between $G/H$ and $G'/H'$, right?  Not between $G$ and $G'/H'$.  Your task wasn't to prove that $|G|=|G'/H'|$ (which is false in many cases).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map

$$\Phi \colon \{ \text{cosets of H} \} \to \{ \text{cosets of H'} \},\ xH \mapsto \phi(x)H'  $$

and show that $\Phi$ is well-defined and bijective.