# Check the proof of the following question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I try to write a proof of the following question: [prove that $H\cap K$ have finite index in G](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605121/prove-that-h-cap-k-have-finite-index-in-g)

> If $G$ is a group and $H,K$ are two subgroups of finite index in $G$, prove that $H\cap K$ is of finite index in $G$. Can you find upper bound for index of $H\cap K$  in $G$?

My proof:
Claim: $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $G$. Moreover, the intersection of two left cosets $xH\cap yK$ for $x\in G$ and $y\in G$ is either empty or is a coset of $H\cap K$.

By this claim, we have that all left cosets of $H\cap K$ is just equal to the intersection of $xH$ and $yK$ for all $x\in G, y\in G$. Hence,
$$
\cup_{g\in G} g(H\cap K)=\cup_{x, y\in G} (xH\cap yK)
$$

Can we say that $$[G:H\cap K]<\infty$$

---

I am not sure how to clear describe the index $[G:H\cap K]$ is finite by our claim?

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea works, you only need to consider representatives instead of all the elements. That is, when you write
$$
\bigcup_{x\in G, y\in G} xH\cap yK
$$
there are several repeated terms in this union. Let $T$ be a set of representatives of the cosets of $H$ and $S$ be a set of representatives of the cosets of $K$. This means, for example, that for every $g\in G$ there exists an *unique* $t\in T$ such that $gH=tH$ (and similarly for $K$ and $S$). Now, note that
$$
[G:H]=|T| \quad \text{and} \quad [G:K]=|S|.
$$
Now you can see that
$$
G = \bigcup_{t\in T, s\in S} tH\cap sK,
$$
and from this
$$
[G:H\cap K]\leq |S\times T| = [G:H][G:K],
$$
and conclude.

Comment: Can I ask why $[G: H\cap K]\le |S\times T|$?