# Let $|G|$ be infinite. Use normal cores (not Poincaré's Theorem) to prove that if $H, K$ have finite index in $G$, then so does $H\cap K$.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups, infinite-groups

This is **Exercise 7.4** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24H%2C%20K%24%20finite%20index%20%24G%24%20infinite%20%20%24H%5Ccap%20K&p=10), it is new to MSE. [This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=if+H+and+K+have+finite+index+in+infinite+G%2C+then+so+does+H+intersect+K&oq=if+H+and+K+have+finite+index+in+infinite+G%2C+then+so+does+H+intersect+K&aqs=chrome..69i57.56877j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) yields [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128538/104041), which is close but does not have the restriction to normal cores nor the prohibition of Poincaré's Theorem.

### The Details:

On page 62 of Roman's book, there is

> **Poincaré's Theorem:** Let $H_1, \dots, H_n\le G$ and $[G: H_i]<\infty$ for all $i$ and let $I_k=H_1\cap\dots\cap H_k$. Then *Poincaré's Inequality* holds:
>
> $$[G: H_1\cap \dots\cap H_n]\le [G: H_1]\dots[G: H_n]$$
>
> and so, in particular, $[G: H_1\cap \dots\cap H_n]$ is also finite.
>
> 1. The inequality above can be replaced can be replaced by division if $$I_kH_k\le G\tag{1}$$ for all $k\in\{1,\dots, n-1\}$.
> 2. Equality holds in Poincaré's Inequality if and only if $$[I_kH_{k+1}:H_{k+1}]=[G:H_{k+1}]$$ for all $k\in\{1,\dots, n-1\}$. Hence, if $G$ is finite or $(1)$ holds for all $k$, then equality holds in Poincaré's Inequality if and only if $$I_kH_{k+1}=G$$ for all $k\in\{1,\dots, n-1\}$.

On page 125 *ibid.*, we have, within a theorem, the

> **Definition:** Let $H\le G$. The largest subgroup of $H$ that is normal in $G$ is called the *normal interior* or *core* of $H$, which we denote by $H^\circ$.

### The Question:

This question is from the chapter on group actions and the structure of $p$-groups, although I think the latter topic is not relevant here.

> **Exercise 7.4:** Let $G$ be an infinite group. Use normal interiors (not Poincaré's Theorem) to prove that if $H$ and $K$ have finite index in $G$, then so does $H\cap K$.

### Context:

As I said above, I think group actions are relevant here. Indeed, the theorem the definition above is in goes like this:

> **Theorem 4.19:** Let $H\le G$. [. . .] The core of $H$ is the kernel $$H^\circ=\bigcap_{a\in G}H^a$$ of the action $\sigma$ of $G$ on $G/H$ by left translation.

*Proof (p.125):* We have

$$\begin{align}
\ker(\sigma)&=\{x\in G\mid \sigma_x={\rm id}\}\\
&=\{x\in G\mid xaH=aH, \forall a\in G\}\\
&=\{x\in G\mid xa\in aH, \forall a\in G\}\\
&=\{x\in G\mid x\in a^{-1}Ha, \forall a\in G\}\\
&=\bigcap_{a\in G} H^a.
\end{align}$$ $\square$

Thus, if I compose/compare somehow the actions $\sigma_L$ of $G$ on $G/L$ for $L\in\{H,K\}$ in question if possible, then I might get somewhere. I'm not sure how to flesh out this vague idea though.

Do I need to calculate $$(H\cap K)^\circ=\bigcap_{g\in G}(H\cap K)^g?$$ If so, I'm not sure how it helps.

(Here $L^g$ is $g^{-1}Lg$.)

Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $G/H$ is finite, $G/H^\circ$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a finite symmetric group, i.e., $H^\circ$ is also of finite index. Likewise, $K^\circ$ is of finite index.
Then the kernel of the obvious homomorphism $G\to G/H^\circ \times G/K^\circ$ is also of finite index and is clearly contained in $H\cap K$.

Comment: Thank you. What you've typed makes sense but I'm not sure how it shows $[G:H\cap K]<\infty$. Please elaborate.

Comment: Ah, now I get it! Thank you.