# Let $G$ be a group and $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$ of finite indices. Show that $H\cap K$ is of finite index.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$ of finite indices. Show that $H\cap K$ is of finite index.

I was trying to solve this problem by using the formula $o(HK)=\frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H\cap K}.$ But the problem is, that nowhere it's given $H$ and $K$ are finite, so we cant use this formula. Next, I tried using the fact:  $H$ and $K$ are two subgroups of $G.$ Let $a,b$ in $G$ then $Ha\cap Kb=\phi$ or there exists  a $c\in G$ such that $(H\cap K)c=Ha\cap Kb.$ I proved this result stated above but I am not attaching it here because I found out that this is a rather popular one. (However, if someone feels that attaching the proof of this would be helpful incase, please, feel free to let me know.) Finally, after searching a while on the internet and looking at some strategies to solve these problems, I wrote out a solution which goes like this:

> Given $H,K\leq G.$ Let the set of right cosets of $H,K$ be $H'=\{Hg_{i_1},...Hg_{i_k}\},K'=\{Kg_{j_1},...,Kg_{j_k}\}$ respectively. Now, say, $(H\cap K)g_{k_1}$ is a right coset of  $H\cap K.$ Then, $Hg_{k_1}\in H'$ and $Kg_{k_1}\in K'$ as $H',K'$ are finite. Since $g_{k_1}$ is arbitary so we see $\forall (H\cap K)g_{k_1}$ $\exists i_p,j_p$ such that $Hg_{k_1}=H{i_p}\in H'$ and $Kg_{k_1}=K{j_p}\in K'$, thus, we conclude the set of cosets of $H\cap K$ finite since $H',K'$ is finite and we see that we can map every cose of $H\cap K$ to a coset of $H$ and $K$.

**Is the above solution, correct? If not, where is it going wrong?**

This link [Does the intersection of two finite index subgroups have finite index?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128538/does-the-intersection-of-two-finite-index-subgroups-have-finite-index) does not answer my question as there the user asks for a solution but I am asking this to validate my solution, i.e whether *this solution* is correct or not? I posted a solution and edited the OP to make it a solution verification post.

Comment: Okay, my answer before was dead wrong, I am sorry. I hadn't worked with algebra for a while and jumped a bit to fast with my conclusions. Maybe have a look at:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128538/does-the-intersection-of-two-finite-index-subgroups-have-finite-index?rq=1

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray I have edite my question a bit? Mind looking at it, to ensure whether it's valid, I mean the solution, I posted?What do you think?....

Comment: Looks correct to me, but so did my proof ^^

Comment: The notation makes no sense. What is $i_p$ in terms of the elements? I think you mean $H_{g_{i_p}}$, etc. Even so, the argument is at least incompete (and thus incorrect). You would need to show that distinct cosets correspond to distinct pairs of cosets. Otherwise, all you have is a function from cosets of $H\cap K$ to pairs of cosets $(Ha,Kb)$. If this association is not one-to-one, then the finiteness of the target set does not imply finiteness of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

With $B$ a subgroup, $A$ a union of cosets of $B$, we denote $\frac{|A|}{|B|}$ the number of cosets of $B$ in $A$.

We have $\frac{|H|}{|H\cap K|}=\frac{|HK|}{|K|}$.

Note that $H=\{h(H\cap K)\mid h\in H\}$ and $HK=\{hK\mid h\in H\}$.

For $h_1,h_2\in H$, we have
$$h_1 K=h_2 K\iff h_1^{-1} h_2\in K \iff h_1^{-1} h_2\in 
H\cap K\iff h_1 (H\cap K)= h_2 (H\cap K),$$
that is, we have a bijection between $h(H\cap K)$ and $hK$.

The above proof works for infinite groups.

We have
$$\frac{|H |}{|H\cap K|} =\frac{|HK|}{|K|}\leq \frac{|G|}{|K|}<\infty,$$
$$\frac{|G|}{|H\cap K|}=\frac{|G|}{|H|}\cdot \frac{|H |}{|H\cap K|}<\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks! But is my answer correct?

Comment: @Franklin You show the map, but do not show it is injective (of course it must be). So you can not conclude directly the finiteness.